# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - Would like to fail when delimiters don't match

Tags: mysql, airflow, mysql-python, temporary-files

I am attempting to use MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE function in airflow to populate a table from a temp file. The issue I am having, is that when delimiters don't match what is expected, I only get warning messages and the load continues anyway. Is it possible to use the LOCAL load and get the sql to fail entirely if the delimiters don't match? This is causing incorrect data to be loaded to the table when I'd prefer it to fail instead.

I attempted the non-local version LOAD DATA INFILE but I get permission errors, because my temp file and mysql server are on different hosts, so I think I am stuck with using the LOCAL option.

```
    temp_to_table = MySQLOperator(
      task_id='temp_to_table',
      conn_id=mysql_conn_id,
      sql="""
      LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='file_path') }}' 
       INTO TABLE airflow.users_test 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\x01'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\x02';
      """,
      autocommit=True
      )
```

Here are some of the warning messages I get, but the data continues loading to the table:

```
[2021-03-02 16:03:03,742] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - /opt/airflow/plugins/mysql_plugins.py:89: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1")
  cur.execute(self.sql)
[2021-03-02 16:03:03,742] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - /opt/airflow/plugins/mysql_plugins.py:89: Warning: (1261, "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns")

  cur.execute(self.sql)
[2021-03-02 16:03:03,743] {logging_mixin.py:112} WARNING - /opt/airflow/plugins/mysql_plugins.py:89: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'superuser' at row 2")
```

Comment: *The issue I am having, is that when delimiters don't match what is expected, I only get warning messages and the load continues anyway.* Depends on current SQL mode. Set it to strict for a session, and the query will fail. But the rows loaded prior to error detection **will not be removed** !! If it is not safe then 1) LOAD DATA must be executed exclusively (lock destination table) 2) autoutilised created_at column must present in table structure.

Comment: As a palliative you may load the whole file into a variable using LOAD_FILE() function, detect correct delimter using common string functions, then execute correct LOAD DATA query (or even build it dynamically)/